# Mocking superagent post request with nock not matching

Tags: mocking, mocha.js, superagent, nock

I cannot for the life of me get nock to work with a simple superagent post request.  Here is both my superagent and nock configuration.

superagent:

```
request
  .post('https://test.com/api/login')
  .send({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: 'testpassword'
  })
  .end((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

nock:

```
nock('https://test.com')
  .post('/api/login')
  .send({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: 'testpassword'
  })
  .reply(200, {
    id: 1,
    token: 'abc'
  });
```

I'm receiving the following error from nock:

> { [Error: Nock: No match for request POST
>   https://test.com/api/login
>   {"email":"test@test.com","password":"testpassword"}] status: 404,
>   statusCode: 404, response: undefined }

Another weird aspect is that this error is being logged in my superagent response handler.  So I know the call is being made and intercepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok -- figured it out.  After digging through the docs a bit more I found the .log function.  I chained my nock config like so

```
nock('https://test.com')
    .log(console.log)...
```

and it turns out the request bodies were not matching.

Comment: Saved a heaps of time

Comment: It looks like the interface for nock has changed (related to post). Instead of chaining the call to ".post("/api").send({..})", you now seem to need to do ".post("/api", {..})". Hope this helps - I'm using nock v8.

Answer (score 0):

`.send()` is replaced by sending the post body as a second param after the url itself and `.log` doesn't work before `.reply`